# Why is the intellisense not working on this case?

Tags: flutter, dart

new flutter programmer here. I just want to understand why the intellisense not suggesting on this case.

Here's is my code:

```
      final ObsController obsController = Get.put(ObsController());
      RxList<dynamic> priceNameListObs = [].obs;
...
      //get the data in firebase
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documentSnapshotPriceDateAfter =
          await db.collection(Paths.priceDatesPath).doc(uid).get();

      priceDateTime = OwnerPriceDates.fromFirestore(documentSnapshotPriceDateAfter);
      //sort the map
      final splayPriceDateTime =
          SplayTreeMap<dynamic, dynamic>((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
      splayPriceDateTime.addAll(priceDateTime!.priceDates!);
      //store in obs
      obsController.populatePriceDateTimeObs(splayPriceDateTime);
```

I tried to fetch the nth index of the `priceDatesNameListObs` but I don't understand why the `toDate` won't appear in the intellisense. Although this works fine.

```
        print('DEBUG: j $j ${obsController.priceDatesNameListObs[1][1].toDate()}');
```

Just showing this in case it is also needed

```
void populatePriceDateTimeObs(SplayTreeMap<dynamic, dynamic> _splayPriceDates) {
    priceDatesNameListObs.clear();
    _splayPriceDates.forEach((key, value) {
      List<Timestamp> _dateTime = [];
      _dateTime.add(value['priceDateTime01']);
      _dateTime.add(value['priceDateTime02']);
      _dateTime.add(value['priceDateTime03']);
      priceDatesNameListObs.add(_dateTime);
    });
  }
```

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class OwnerPriceDates {
  Map<String, dynamic>? prices;

  OwnerPriceDates({
    required this.prices,
  });

  factory OwnerPriceDates.fromFirestore(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
    Map? data = doc.data();

    if (data == null) {
      return OwnerPriceDates(
        prices: {},
      );
    }

    return OwnerPriceDates(
      prices: data['prices'],
    );
  }

  factory OwnerPriceDates.fromMap(Map data) {
    return OwnerPriceDates(
      prices: data['prices'],
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class PriceDates {
  Timestamp? priceDateTime01;
  Timestamp? priceDateTime02;
  Timestamp? priceDateTime03;

  PriceDates({
    required this.priceDateTime01,
    required this.priceDateTime02,
    required this.priceDateTime03,
  });

  factory PriceDates.fromHashmap(Map<PriceDates, dynamic> priceDateTime) {
    return PriceDates(
      priceDateTime01: priceDateTime['priceDateTime01'],
      priceDateTime02: priceDateTime['priceDateTime02'],
      priceDateTime03: priceDateTime['priceDateTime03'],
    );
  }
}
```

Here's what it looks like my collection in firebase:

```
priceDates > priceDate1 > priceDateTime01: February 13, 2022 at 12:33:54 AM UTC+3
                          priceDateTime02: February 13, 2022 at 12:33:54 AM UTC+3
                          priceDateTime03: February 13, 2022 at 12:33:54 AM UTC+3
             priceDate2 > priceDateTime01: February 13, 2022 at 12:33:54 AM UTC+3
                          priceDateTime02: February 13, 2022 at 12:33:54 AM UTC+3
                          priceDateTime03: February 13, 2022 at 12:33:54 AM UTC+3
             priceDate3 > priceDateTime01: February 13, 2022 at 12:33:54 AM UTC+3
                          priceDateTime02: February 13, 2022 at 12:33:54 AM UTC+3
                          priceDateTime03: February 13, 2022 at 12:33:54 AM UTC+3
```

Answer (score 0):

The most probable explanation is that `priceDatesNameListObs` is of type dynamic. In this case the intellisense cannot guess what are the members of `priceDatesNameListObs[1][1]`.

Change the type of `priceDatesNameListObs` to a static type, if possible, then you should get intellisense working.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Thanks!